# Visual Studio 2010 setup project - how to add manifest to it - SupportedOS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

I'm getting the following error when running the Microsoft Platform Ready Test Tool:

The following executables failed the validation:

=== Executables with manifest that don't support the latest OS ===

C:\QES\Application\setup.exe

I can figure out how to create the manifest for the main project but I can't figure out how to add a manifest to the setup project so that I can add the supportedOS line into it.

Thanks!

Comment: Setup projects generate MSI files, and these don't use manifests to say what OS the MSI can be installed on. The setup.exe is the bootstrapper to install prerequisites and the MSI, and it's not .NET. It's not clear how this is connected with Platform Ready Test - surely you're testing your own code, not Microsoft's setup packages?